# PHP Photo Effects

Tags: php, facebook, editor, effects, photo

I am working on a new site and would like it to be able to add effects to photos uploaded. (Blur, Pan, Swirl, Sparkle, Border, Frames, etc ) I would like the photo manipulation to be in PHP if possible. I need the user to be able to upload the photo, make the edits, then save the edited photo to their computer.

---

This may be better as a separate question, but if at all possible I would also like the user to be able to save the edited image as their Facebook profile image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PHP extensions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=8hhddgbf5erfs2u4e19fg54f41#php) for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) It's a standard, tried and true image manipulation library.

From the homepage:

> Use ImageMagick to translate, flip,
>   mirror, rotate, scale, shear and
>   transform images, adjust image colors,
>   apply various special effects, or draw
>   text, lines, polygons, ellipses and
>   Bézier curves.

**If you consider using the MagickWand PHP extension:**

The [MagicWand docs](http://www.magickwand.org/)  start off with a nice PHP code sample shown here:

```
<?php
  $magick_wand=NewMagickWand();
  MagickReadImage($magick_wand,'rose.jpg');
  $drawing_wand=NewDrawingWand();
  DrawSetFont($drawing_wand,"/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf");
  DrawSetFontSize($drawing_wand,20);
  DrawSetGravity($drawing_wand,MW_CenterGravity);
  $pixel_wand=NewPixelWand();
  PixelSetColor($pixel_wand,"white");
  DrawSetFillColor($drawing_wand,$pixel_wand);
  if (MagickAnnotateImage($magick_wand,$drawing_wand,0,0,0,"Rose") != 0)
    {
      MagickEchoImageBlob( $magick_wand );
    }
  else
    {
      echo MagickGetExceptionString($magick_wand);
    }
?>
```

Similarily, documentation for things you seek:

- [blur](http://www.magickwand.org/MagickBlurImage.html)
- [swirl](http://www.magickwand.org/MagickSwirlImage.html)
- [frame](http://www.magickwand.org/MagickFrameImage.html)
- [magnify](http://www.magickwand.org/MagickMagnifyImage.html)
- and a plethora of others.... On that the **[main documentation page](http://www.magickwand.org/)** see all methods listed by searching for the heading: "**MagickWand For PHP Methods**".

Comment: I love ImageMagick, especially MagickWand so far, but can't figure out how to install it to my server. I have purchased hosting from a company (mrpuma.com) that provide CPanel hosting. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no ideas off the top of my head. However you might get good feedback if you reformulate it as another question, maybe as a server issue on companion site http://serverfault.com/